# Can python2.7 be compiled for Windows10 ARM64

Tags: python-2.7, windows-10, arm64

Today all our infrastructure is based on python 2.7.2 and we want to use it on Windows10 ARM64 machine as well. But in the link below, you can see that the ARM64 compiler is included in VS2017 and not in previous versions.
So no chance to compile python 2.7 for windows10 ARM64?
Did someone try that? 
What are your suggestions?

https://wiki.python.org/moin/WindowsCompilers

Answer (score 0):

I've just ran into this, I know it's a little late but never late than never.

I'm just in the process of building Python 2.7 for Windows aarch64. It seems to work with some minor patches (mainly required to get it to compile with MSVC2017, since 2.7 is usually compiled on the ancient MSVC2008, which doesn't have a native aarch64 compiler).

The interpreter seems to work just fine but I still need to finish building all the included modules before I can say it's ready. Right now I got around half of them running and I hope I can get the rest working soon. The biggest pain is going to be ctypes, I think I'll get it working eventually but issues are expected.

If this is still relevant please post a reply and I'll share it when I'm done building everything.

EDIT: Just finished, download Python 2.7 ARM64 and a bunch of other ARM64 open source programs and libraries from here -
https://mega.nz/#F!PclhDIRB!-yhBZ6UM7S596ijNU3dx0A